# Django simple-pages stable or not?

Tags: django, django-flatpages

I want to create a pretty simple site with a few pages using Django. I guess I could use Wordpress. But there is some custom stuff (like a special kind of calendar app) that I rather do in Python than PHP.

I came across simple-pages which seems like a nice middle way between flat-pages and a fullblown Django CMS (which just seems overkill). It can automatically generate menus. But it seems like it hasn't been updated in a long time. Is it deprecated or is it stable? Or do flat-pages have the same functionality these days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, It would be super easy to build your own small custom CMS since you know python. It would only take a few models and not a lot of time - the result being something better customized for your needs.

I've used some of these examples before - and they work ok, but I always find myself having to add something more.

One idea is to check out what sub-applications some of these things are using - maybe import only what you really need.

But I almost always find myself spending a LITTLE extra time to build out my own schema/structure for simple pages Then using a nice admin skin like grappelli when handing it over to clients (you get SORT of that wordpress feel (sort of))

Lots of admin customization that can make it easy for clients (and You) to work with static pages.